# Creating Hyperlink in IR report

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

How, in oracle apex, can I link Information in a table to a different external page from an interactive report column?

The page being linked to will display different data, depending on which IP the user clicked.

I know hyperlink uses href but oracle apex uses links but am not getting any to work

an example of what am doing is

i have  an IR report and one of the columns has IP addresses , when the user clicks the IP address

it suppose to send them to a different location on our server.

```
 100.100.100.100- should send me to the Printers

 100.100.100.101 -should send me to Drivers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I understood the question.

- `TEST` CTE represents your table
- one of its columns is `ip_address'
- depending on that value, you want to navigate to some URL

One option to do it is to use `CASE` (or `DECODE`, but - `CASE` is easier to read & maintain) and explicitly decide where you want to go, depending on each `ip_address` value - that's what my example shows.

Another is to expand the table (`alter table ...`), add another column and put exact URL in there. That scales better, because - if you ever add a new row into that table, you'll have to edit interactive report's query and add yet another `CASE` option, which is *stupid*. I suggest you to alter table.

Anyway, here you go: it is an interactive report query. Nothing special about it, just pay attention to edit `link` column's properties and set "Escape special characters" to "No".

```
with test (id, name, ip_address) as
  (select 1, 'Google', '100.100.100.100' from dual union all
   select 2, 'Bing'  , '100.100.100.101' from dual
  )
select 
  id, 
  name,
  '<a href="' || case 
                  when ip_address = '100.100.100.100' then 'https://www.google.com'
                  when ip_address = '100.100.100.101' then 'https://www.bing.com'
                end
              || '" target="_blank">' || ip_address || '</a>' as link
from test;
```

**[EDIT]**

If table contains URL itself, then I'd suggest something like this:

```
with test (id, name, ip_address, url) as
  (select 1, 'Google', '100.100.100.100', 'https://www.google.com' from dual union all
   select 2, 'Bing'  , '100.100.100.101', 'https://www.bing.com'   from dual
  )
select 
  id, 
  '<a href="' || url || '" target="_blank">' || name || '</a>' as link
from test;
```

This query will show `name` as a hyperlink. Why? Because I think that seeing e.g. "Google" is more acceptable than seeing e.g. "100.100.100.101". People usually prefer *names* over *numbers*. See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge littlefoot , i am choosing to use the alter table option , however this comes back to the original issue which is ,if i create a column and call it "URL" then i add    url-https://www.google.com how am i gonna make https://www.google.com a hyperlink because remember the next row will have bing.com as hyperlink as well.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer; have a look, please.

Comment: i am not getting this to work at all. i am using your second option  which states 'Another is to expand the table (alter table ...), add another column and put exact URL in there'  but this is not changing into a url link or anything to the sort . can you further assist?

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work for you; works for me, I tested it before posting the answer. By the way, did you set "Escape special characters" to "No"? If it still doesn't work, please, create a sample application on apex.oracle.com, let us know username/password so that someone might have a look at it.

Comment: hi little foot , workspace-url    , username-rawlemusgrave4@hotmail.com, password-R@wle23*

Comment: Thank you. I've created 2 pages: 4 (interactive report) and 5 (classic report). In order to make it work, I also modified table contents and entered full address; you "forgot" to add "https://" in both rows. Have a look.

Comment: Or I total understand what u have done , Thank you again @littlefoot

Comment: You're welcome. It would be nice if you upvoted/accepted the answer.

Comment: Is there a was i can get the external website to show as a modal in oracle apex?. so instead of google.com opening in a new tab i will like it to open as a modal in apex.

Comment: I never did that, but - Google for **iframe** and see whether it helps.

Comment: thank you was looking into iframe but didnt get anything much will still look more.